# Question about L'Hospital's Rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I am studying reals out of Bartle and Sherbert, and it seems to me that one of their hypotheses in the statement of L'Hospital's rule is unnecessary, but I just want to check that I am not missing something.

They have a version of L'Hospital's rule (thm 6.3.1, pg 181 in their book) where we consider the interval $[\alpha,\beta]$, $f$ and $g$ real valued functions defined on $[\alpha,\beta]$ such that

- $f(\alpha) = g(\alpha) = 0$
- $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable at $\alpha$
- $g'(\alpha) \neq 0$
- $g(x) \neq 0$ for $\alpha < x < \beta$

It seems to me the last condition is unnecessary since the derivative of $g$ non-zero at $\alpha$ implies there exists a right neighborhood of $\alpha$ on which $g$ is non-zero.

Is this correct or is there something subtle I am missing here?

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: It's convenience. Without that assumption, you'd only know $g(x)\neq 0$ for $\alpha < x < \gamma$ for some $\gamma > \alpha$. To ease notation and formulation, one assumes that $\beta$ is chosen small enough to begin with.

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Just wanted to check though. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is a typo? The usual condition is $g'(x)\ne 0$ near $\alpha$. But $g'(\alpha)\ne 0$ **is** unnecessary. In fact the derivability of $g$ in $\alpha$ is unnecessary.

Comment: No b/c, later he does derive the more general form of L'Hospital's rule (which is what you're considering) where he dispenses with the condition that the derivative of f and g at the LH endpoint need exist (just the LH limits of their derivatives). In this simpler version though, he just divides numerator and denominator by (x-$\alpha$) and the takes the limits of both directly.